# How to get AntD expanded Table to display nested dataSource values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have to dynamically render some data into antD expandable table. The data is a nested object with various properties -

```
const values = [
    [name = 'Josh', city = 'Sydney', pincode='10000'],
    [name = 'Matthew', city = 'London', pincode = '20000'],
    [name = 'Roger', city = 'Paris', pincode = '2300'],
]
```

How can I display this data in an antD table? The dataSource = {values} gives an empty table.
Kindly guide me. How to display nested array values in the antD table?

Comment: Kindly refer this link, It says Array[Data] and also a Array[Columns] is required
https://ant.design/components/table/#How-To-Use

Comment: Hi, I've already checked the documentation. I have columns for the table, but I want to set the dataSource for the table as a state

Comment: wrap in a useState hook and you can set them from API, That should be fine ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been trying. Actually, so here is my goal - I need to dynamically render data into the antD expandable table, if there is data in the useState hook then dataSource={hookData} else it should be the data calculated within within the expandRowRender method. Is this possible? Currently I have written - dataSource={ hookData !=null ? hookData : tableVal}

Comment: Please help if you have some idea

Comment: so in that case, you want to handle if the data is empty ? Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, so say state hookData is null, then within the expandRowRender method there is some logic i have written to display, say that value is 'result'. If hookData is null, then result should be used in dataSource, else the state value of hookData

Comment: I've given dataSource ={ hookData !null = ? hookData : result}

Comment: Okay so what you can do is to assign the hookData to an empty arry by default, perform the API and if the data is empty, then donot update the hookData, So by default the hookData will have the length of the array as 0, So you can modify the condition to be {hookData.length ? hookData : result}

Comment: Ah thank you, this makes sense. Will try it out now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the data you are trying to pass is totally wrong, it should be an array of objects,

```
const values = [
  {key: '1', name: 'Josh', city: 'Sydney', pincode:'10000'},
  {key: '1',name:'Matthew', city: 'London', pincode:'20000'},
  {key: '3',name: 'Roger', city:'Paris', pincode: '2300'},
]
```

and second, as you read the [Table](https://ant.design/components/table/#How-To-Use) sample code given on documentation, you also need to pass the table's header,

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'City',
    dataIndex: 'city',
    key: 'city',
  },
  {
    title: 'Pincode',
    dataIndex: 'pincode',
    key: 'pincode',
  },
]
```

Comment: I have converted the array of arrays into an array of objects and also given the table header inside the expandRowRender method for the expandable table. They key values in the array of objects are the same